# Regex Expression works fine in online testers, but not working on my page

Tags: php, css, regex

So I am reading a css file, and I want to get some data out of it. I currently trimmed down the data purely to this:

```
font-family: "Verdana";
font-size: 14px;
color: #000000;
```

and to purely get the data I need (namely Verdana, 14 and #000000), I created the following PHP code:

```
foreach($tmp as $tmpstr){
        if(strpos($tmpstr, "font-family")){
            $tmpres = array();
            preg_match('/\"(.*?)\"/', $tmpstr, $tmpres);
            $returnData["website"]["font-family"] = $tmpres[1];
        } else if(strpos($tmpstr, "font-size")){
            $tmpres2 = array();
            preg_match_all('/\:\s(.*?)px\;/', $tmpstr, $tmpres2);
            $returnData["website"]["font-size"] = $tmpres2[1];
        } else if(strpos($tmpstr, "color")){
            $tmpres3 = array();
            preg_match_all('/color\:\s(.*?)\;/', $tmpstr, $tmpres3);
            $returnData["website"]["font-color"] = $tmpres3[1];
        }
    }
```

I know it is not optimized yet, but the reason for that is, is that it isn't working. The first expression `'/\"(.*?)\"/'` to get Verdana works fine, but the other two (`'/\:\s(.*?)px\;/'` to get the font size, `/color\:\s(.*?)\;/` to get the font color) don't, whereas testing them in an online tester does seem to work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: the other 2 don't run, because of the if\ele structure, consider your logic again

Comment: As the first one works, it's probably not the problem but note that `strpos()` can return `0` so you need to compare it to `false` like: `if(strpos($tmpstr, "font-size") !== false)`

Comment: use preg match all, is it a file of just css styles? you can extract the whole file to an array with, preg match all, and then process as much as you need to, once its in a usable array structure.

Comment: I would update your \s to be \s* ( 0 or more ) its perfectly valid css this way ( font-family:"Verdana", font-family:  "Verdana" < tabbed ), id also advise not removing the px as it could be pt, or em here.  Of course that depends on if you have control of the css file completely and what the end goal is.

Comment: @jeroen I completely forgot about that! I am used to Java's "StartsWith()" function, which just returns true or false, and even though the function name tells me it is going to return a number, I didn't think about that it could return 0. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example

```
$tmp = array(
    'font-family: "Verdana";',
    'font-size: 14px;',
    'color: #000000;'
);

foreach($tmp as $tmpstr)
{
    if (false !== strpos($tmpstr, "font-family"))
    {
        preg_match('/:[ ]*"(.*)"/', $tmpstr, $tmpres);
        echo $tmpres[1];
    } 
    else if (false !== strpos($tmpstr, "font-size"))
    {
        preg_match('/:[ ]*(\d*)px/', $tmpstr, $tmpres2);
        echo $tmpres2[1];
    } 
    else if (false !== strpos($tmpstr, "color"))
    {
        preg_match('/:[ ]*(.*);/', $tmpstr, $tmpres3);
        echo $tmpres3[1];
    }

    echo '<br />';
}
```

Result:

```
Verdana
14
#000000
```

Hope this solution help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$css = 'font-family: "Verdana";
font-size: 14px;
color: #000000;'


preg_match_all('(?P<key>.+?)\:\s*(?P<value>.+?)\;', $css, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => font-family: "Verdana";
            [key] => font-family
            [1] => font-family
            [value] => "Verdana"
            [2] => "Verdana"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => font-size: 14px;
            [key] => font-size
            [1] => font-size
            [value] => 14px
            [2] => 14px
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => color: #000000;
            [key] => color
            [1] => color
            [value] => #000000
            [2] => #000000
        )

)
```

Then it should be a trivial matter of doing a foreach loop to clean up the output:

```
$data = array()
foreach($result as $r){
  $data[$r['key']] = $r['value'];
}
```

Outputs:

```
array
(
     [font-family] => "Verdana",
     [font-size] => 14px,
     [color] => #000000
)
```

As a side note you could extend this for the whole file:

```
/(?P<selectors>.*?)\s*\{|(?P<key>.+?)\:\s*(?P<value>.+?)\;/



 #id, and some class
    {
    font-family: "Verdana";
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000000;
    }

   #id2, and some class1
    { ..... and so on.
```

Outputs:

```
array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => #id, and some class
{
            [selectors] => #id, and some class ///you may want to post process this and split on comma etc.
            [1] => #id, and some class
        )



       [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => font-family: "Verdana";
                [selectors] => 
                [1] => 
                [key] => font-family
                [2] => font-family
                [value] => "Verdana"
                [3] => "Verdana"
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => font-size: 14px;
                [selectors] => 
                [1] => 
                [key] => font-size
                [2] => font-size
                [value] => 14px
                [3] => 14px
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => color: #000000;
                [selectors] => 
                [1] => 
                [key] => color
                [2] => color
                [value] => #000000
                [3] => #000000
             )
         [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => #id2, and some class1
    {
                [selectors] => #id2, and some class1
                [1] => #id2, and some class1
            ) .....
```

update, sorry you'll want to check if empty ( previously i had isset ) as I see that $r['selectors'] is set in each of them. Then you can sub array each style block by its selector, and parse to your hart's content. You get the idea, but if you need help with that bit just ask ( it may be better to remove the PRET_SET_ORDER in that case ) ...

this would be my suggested end structure for a css file..

```
array(
selector => array( color => 'bla', font => blabla )
selector2 => array( ..... 
)
```

I think preg_match_all doesn't get the attention it needs, it can be really useful for this kind of thing, if your not familiar with it check it out at the php doc http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: This does get the job well done, but it is (for now) more than I want. If I decide to use the whole css file, I could use this =)